# Javascript Parser Error While Trying To Include SVG Element as Functional React Component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, svg

I am building a React application that serves as a community directory for a global music scene I am a part of. I am trying to follow an SVG icon strategy that wraps the SVG code with a functional React component so that you can then import the icon into the component that uses it as a React component ([NYT Article that outlines the strategy](https://open.nytimes.com/flexible-icons-with-react-svg-973f310e6382)). This strategy is working for some components, but for many, I am getting parsing errors along the lines of:

```js
./src/Components/LargeScopeComponents/ArtistProfileDisplay/TopBar/SVG/ListViewIcon/ListViewIconDarkTheme.js
  Line 4:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "}"

  2 | 
  3 | const ListViewIconDarkTheme = () => (
> 4 |  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 57.72 53.2"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:#fff}</style></defs><g id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2"><g id="Layer_1-2" data-name="Layer 1"><path class="cls-1" d="M15.38 41.72h42.35V53.2H15.38zM.41 41.72h10.86V53.2H.41zM15.15 20.86H57.5v11.48H15.15zM0 20.86h10.86v11.48H0zM15.15 0H57.5v11.48H15.15zM0 0h10.86v11.48H0z"/></g></g></svg>
    |                                                                                           ^
  5 | );
  6 | 
  7 | export default ListViewIconDarkTheme;
```

I'm not completely sure why the javascript parser doesn't like the SVG syntax, because this strategy is working for other components. For example, I used the same strategy to create this functional component, and the javascript parser did not complain when I included it in a card component I use it in.

```js
import React from 'react';

const CircleUpIcon_LightTheme = () => (
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 83.28 83.28"><g data-name="Layer 2"><g data-name="Layer 1"><circle cx="41.64" cy="41.64" r="38.64" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="6"/><path d="M41.64 20.7L20.92 56.58h41.43L41.64 20.7z"/></g></g></svg>
);

export default CircleUpIcon_LightTheme;
```

I'm wondering if there are any workarounds to this or modifications I could make to the SVG syntax to please the javascript parser. Any help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that svg syntax clashes with jsx. React supports most svg element types (see: https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#all-supported-svg-attributes), but for things like `<style>` you need to make the children react compatible. For example:

```
<style>{
  `.cls-1{fill:#fff}`
}</style>
```

Notice the extra braces, and converting the child to a string. This should fix your first error.

Answer (score 0):

The style tag in ListViewIconDarkTheme is causing the problem.

Why don't you try this? (see style attribute)

```
const ListViewIconDarkTheme = () => (
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 57.72 53.2"><g 
id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2"><g id="Layer_1-2" data-name="Layer 1"><path 
class="cls-1" style="fill:#fff" d="M15.38 41.72h42.35V53.2H15.38zM.41 
41.72h10.86V53.2H.41zM15.15 20.86H57.5v11.48H15.15zM0 
20.86h10.86v11.48H0zM15.15 0H57.5v11.48H15.15zM0 0h10.86v11.48H0z"/></g></g> . 
</svg>
);

export default ListViewIconDarkTheme;
```

Comment: Looks like that's getting rid of the errors, thanks a lot! To fit with JSX syntax, I just had to make sure to do style={{fill:'#fff'}} there.